# using char array and boolean array in an if statement with the && operator

Tags: java, arrays, operators

I'm trying to use boolean and char arrays in conjunction with an && operator but am getting an error message stating that char and boolean values may not be used with &&.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

```
private static boolean[] mergeAllCorrectPositions(boolean[] allPositions, char[] wordArray, char x) {
    boolean[] currentPositions = new boolean[wordArray.length];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < wordArray.length ; i++){
        if(wordArray[i] = x && allPositions[i] = false){
            // stuff
        }
    }
    return currentPositions;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You used assignment operator instead of comparison operator.

change

```
if(wordArray[i] = x && allPositions[i] = false)
```

to

```
if(wordArray[i] == x && allPositions[i] == false)
```

or

```
if(wordArray[i] == x && !allPositions[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

= is an assignment operator. To compare the values of primitives, you'll need to use the == operator.
At this point, you are not comparing the values, but setting them.

```
if(wordArray[i] = x && allPositions[i] = false){
```

should be

```
if(wordArray[i] == x && allPositions[i] == false){
```